# npm command not found pm2: command not found

Tags: pm2, nvm

NVM node is installed under Ubuntu19.04 but local pm2 deploy production update will report errors such as pm2: command not found

On the remote server

```
  root@vultr:/usr/bin# git --version
  git version 2.20.1
  root@vultr:/usr/bin# nvm --version
  0.34.0
  root@vultr:/usr/bin# node -v
  v10.15.3
  root@vultr:/usr/bin# npm -v
  6.4.1
```

On the local server

```
  pm2 deploy production update
--> Deploying to production environment
--> on host 202.182.98.13
  ○ deploying origin/master
  ○ executing pre-deploy-local
  ○ hook pre-deploy
  ○ fast forward master
Already on 'master'
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.
From github.com:zq0904/pm2
Updating d79b633..2fe1d22
Fast-forward
 README.md           | 3 ++-
 ecosystem.config.js | 2 +-
 2 files changed, 3 insertions(+), 2 deletions(-)
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
   d79b633..2fe1d22  master     -> origin/master
  ○ executing post-deploy `git pull && npm install && pm2 reload ecosystem.config.js --env production`
Already up to date.
npm WARN 06-pm2@1.0.0 No repository field.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.9 (node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.9: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})

up to date in 3.997s
pm2: command not found

  post-deploy hook failed

Deploy failed
1
```

I can do it on a remote server

```
whereis npm
  lh -s /root/.nvm/versions/node/v10.15.3/bin/node /usr/bin/node
  lh -s /root/.nvm/versions/node/v10.15.3/bin/npm /usr/bin/npm
  lh -s /root/.nvm/versions/node/v10.15.3/bin/pm2 /usr/bin/pm2
```

That would solve the problem，
But I don't understand why，
The server can already output NPM node pm2 and other versions，
But why do I have to set up a soft connection?
Is there any good solution to this troublesome problem，
Thank you very much！

Answer (score 5):

I am not sure what's the root cause of this issue. But, it was happening to me when I created a new user in **AWS EC2 ubuntu** instance and try to deploy my **NodeJS** app using **pm2** through that new user.

##### I followed [this github thread](https://github.com/Unitech/pm2-deploy/issues/41) and [this particular comment](https://github.com/Unitech/pm2-deploy/issues/41#issuecomment-143163458) solved my issue. Simply comment the following line in your server's `.bashrc` file

```js
#If not running interactively, don 't do anything
case $ - in
*
i * );;
*) return;;
esac
```

Answer (score 1):

PM2 does not use interactive shell, so you have to comment out the the following inside `.bashrc`

```
# ~/.bashrc: executed by bash(1) for non-login shells.
# see /usr/share/doc/bash/examples/startup-files (in the package bash-doc)
# for examples


# >>> COMMENT OPUT THE FOLLOWING LINES >>>
# If not running interactively, don't do anything
# case $- in
#    *i*) ;;
#      *) return;;
# esac
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to install pm2 globally

if you have ubuntu system installed try this:-

**sudo npm i -g pm2**

then start with your file

**pm2 start ecosystem.config.js**